# Next.js getInitialProps not rendering on the index.js page

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

I really can't figure out what is wrong with this code on Next.js.
**index.js** :

```js
import { getUsers } from "../utils/users";
import React from "react";

Home.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  let elements = [];
  getUsers().then((res) => {
    res.map((el) => {
      elements.push(el.name);
    });
    console.log(elements);
  });
  return { elements: elements };
};

function Home({ elements }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {elements.map((el, i) => {
        <p key={i}>{el}</p>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

This doesn't render anything on my main page but still console logs the right data on server side (inside the vscode console). I really can't figure out what's going on, I followed precisely the [article](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps) on the next.js site.
The getUsers function is an async function that returns an array of objects (with name,surname props), in this case in the `.then` I'm grabbing the names and pushing them into an array that correctly logs out to the console.
How can I make this data that I get render on the page?? Surely something to do with SSR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is using async function. Try as following.

```
...
elements = await getUsers();
...
```

In your code, component is rendered before response is finished. So the data is not rendered. Suggest using "async...await...". Infact "async" and "await" are like a couple of one.

Comment: Thank you very much man, I didn't realize this simple thing....